# Error JSON.simple: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.class

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, json-simple

I am facing a problem in android studio after adding JSON.simple and enabling MultiDex and get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>    java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.class

Here is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.MildlyGoodApps.EffortlessDescriptions"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Thank you.

### Fixed:

Changed `compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'` to `compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'){ exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core' }`.

Thank you Kane O'Riley!

Comment: That means you have 2 or more dex files defining `org.hamcrest.BaseDescription`. Perhaps post your `build.gradle`, and check your dependencies for duplicate entries of this class. Poorly coded libraries sometimes include external dependency classes directly rather than referring to them correctly.

Comment: Added build.gradle .

Comment: What jars do you have in your `libs` directory?

Comment: I can't find the `libs` directory, but when I remove the line `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` nothing changes and I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the output of running `./gradlew -q api:dependencies --configuration compile` from the project directory? Also, try changing the compile directive for `json-simple` to look like this: `compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') { exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core' }`

Comment: Thank you. Adding `{ exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core' }` worked!

Comment: Cool. I posted as an answer, so if it solved your issue please upvote and accept it :).

Comment: I have accepted it but I haven't got enough reputation to upvote it!

Comment: Oh that's fine, accepting is the important part so others know this solved the issue for you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change your `json-simple` import to exclude the hamcrest dependency like this:

```
compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
```

This will prevent multiple copies of the dependency being included.