# Error: multiple files define Lorg/json/simple/ItemList

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I try to build an APK for my project, this is the error I get:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/simple/ItemList;
```

## build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.here"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.clerezza.ext:org.json.simple:0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

I think that means that more than one dependency defines `ItemList`. I know one is `org.json.simple`, what is the other one?

How do I properly exclude `ItemList` from one of them?

there's nothing in my libs folder so that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this `compile 'org.apache.clerezza.ext:org.json.simple:0.4'`

with

```
compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
```

the source is here: [click link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543197/error-json-simple-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-org-hamcrest-bas)