# Duplicate entry: org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dex, hamcrest

There is another [question that has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543197/error-json-simple-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-org-hamcrest-bas) that does not work for me (as I don't have the library the selected answer has).

I have searched through all my project for the `BaseDescription` and there is only 1 occurrence of the `BaseDescription` and another for a subclass:

[image]

I also went through my `android.iml` file and made and tried removing ever instance of it as a test:

```
   <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="hamcrest-library-1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="hamcrest-integration-1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="hamcrest-all-1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="hamcrest-core-1.3" level="project" />
```

But even after removing that and running a clean and doing the test run, I still get the duplicate entry error (where I would think it would have said class not found at all).

Do you have any idea where else I can find where this duplicate entry is coming from?

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: I just removed it (the jars) entirely, it looks like there was a conflict in the jars. Using `compile` in the deps now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It's because the hamcrest.jar is not included in your library.

- I uninstalled my android studio and deleted all belonged files.Then downloaded a new android studio and installed.During my installation I had connected to a WiFi to download the required packages on time.Now my Gradle sync is completed successfully.